# Probability Problem Involving Combinatorics

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

In a building with 5 floors (excluding the ground floor), an elevator starts with 4 people at the ground floor. Each person is equally likely to leave the lift on any floor except the ground floor. What is the probability that 2 people get off at one floor and 2 people get off at another.

Well, there are 10 possible ways ( i.e C(5,2) ) to select the two floors to get down on. Next, you could arrange 4 people into 2 groups in 3 ways and distribute those groups in 2 ways on the 2 floors. So the probability would be $\frac {10 \times 3\times 2} {625}$ (i.e total favourable outcomes / total outcomes ).Where did I make a mistake?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: We can't identify your error unless you show how you got your answer.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Should say:  I also get $\frac {12}{5^3}$.  My argument:  There are $\binom 52=10$ ways to choose the two special floors.  Then, having chosen the two floors, there are $\binom 42=6$ ways to choose the two people who get off on the lower of the two. Thus, there are $60$ good scenarios out of $5^4$.  And $\frac {60}{5^4}=\frac {12}{5^3}$.

Comment: Well, there are 10 possible ways ( i.e C(5,2) ) to select the two floors to get down on. Next, you could arrange 4 people into 2 groups in 3 ways and distribute those groups in 2 ways on the 2 floors. So the probability would be 10*3*2 / 625 (i.e total favourable outcomes / total outcomes )

Comment: Please edit your post to include that....don't leave it for the comments.  That said, I agree with your computation.

Comment: Made the changes.

Comment: Your computation matches mine...I don't see the problem.  If you care to, you could simulate the problem to test the answer(s) numerically.

Comment: It seems there is a mistake in the answer key. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct, and as you can see, there are a variety of thought processes possible to get at the solution.

If you can visualize a problem as a well known **type**, it becomes an almost  "thought free" process. Here you could think of it as throwing a $5$ sided die $4$ times, so compute the number of ways as the product of two multinomial coefficients,

$\small{[Number\; of\; ways\;] = [Lay\; down\; pattern] \times [Permute\; pattern]\quad}$

to give $\;Pr = \dfrac{\dbinom{4}{2,2,0,0,0}\dbinom{5}{2,3}}{5^4} = \dfrac{12}{5^3}$

## *Added*

If you aren't too conversant with the multinomial coefficient, note that the numerator is *exactly identical* to the same expression written as factorials,

$$Pr = {\dfrac{4!}{2!2!0!0!0!}\cdot\dfrac{5!}{2!3!}\Big{/}{5^4}} = \dfrac{12}{5^3}$$

You can, of course, further simplify the numerator by eliminating $0$ factorials, viz

$$Pr = {\dfrac{4!}{2!2!}\cdot\dfrac{5!}{2!3!}\Big{/}{5^4}} = \dfrac{12}{5^3}$$

but it is advisable to retain the full expression to retain an exact parallel to the die throw analogy.